# Scala make multiple option checks more concise

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

Working with Options in Scala and Play Framework, is there a more concise way of checking x amount of variables like so?

```
if (a.isDefined || b.isDefined || c.isDefined || d.isDefined ...) {

}
```

Is a one liner something like `(a,b,c,d).isDefined` possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On top of my head, probably there's a nicer way:

```
List(a, b, c, d).exists(_.isDefined)
```

For `and`s (from Rob Starling comment):

```
List(a, b, c, d).forall(_.isDefined)
```

You could also have more complex condition compositions:

```
// (a || b) && (c || d)
List(
  List(a, b).exists(_.isDefined), 
  List(c, d).exists(_.isDefined)
).forall(identity)

// (a && b) || (c && d)
List(
  List(a, b).forall(_.isDefined), 
  List(c, d).forall(_.isDefined)
).exists(identity)
```

And so on.

Comment: And if you need `and` instead of `or`, there's `List(a, b, c, d).forall(_.isDefined)`

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you seem to be within the playframework and that you probably not only want to  check whether the / or a value is defined but also use them, you could use the following code using the type classes of the play framework without using scalaz.

```
import play.api.libs.functional._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
implicit def optionInstance[A] = new Applicative[Option] with Alternative[Option] {
  override def pure[A](a: A): Option[A] = Option(a)

  override def apply[A, B](mf: Option[(A) => B], ma: Option[A]): Option[B] = for {
    f <- mf
    a <- ma
  } yield f(a)

  override def map[A, B](m: Option[A], f: (A) => B): Option[B] = m map f

  override def app: Applicative[Option] = this 

  override def `|`[A, B >: A](alt1: Option[A], alt2: Option[B]): Option[B] = {
    (alt1, alt2) match {
      case (Some(_), None) => alt1
      case (None, Some(_)) => alt2
      case _ => None
    }
  }
  override def empty: Option[Nothing] = None
}

// examples

val optI = Option(3)
val optS = Option("Hello")
val optNone : Option[String] = None

(optI and optS ) {(i, s) => s"$i $s"}
(optI and optS and (optNone or Option("world")) ) { (i,s,w) => s"$i $s $w"}
```

Comment: +1, very interesting even though a bit over engineered in this case.

Comment: As I said, I believe that the original function is futile, as you will want to know the values of the options. With the list approach, you get a problem as the lists will be of type List[Option[_]]. Using scalaz you could also omit all the instance definition and just use the applicative instance of Option, aka (optI |@| optS) ...

Comment: My first thoughts were also about how to access the options values later on since the list approach doesn't give you this flexibility, what I didn't know is that you could do it with Scalaz. Consider this though: `(optI and optS or (optNone or Option("world")))`, as I'm a Scalaz newbie, what is gonna happen here? How many parameter will I have to supply in the following anonymous function?

Comment: `or` is jsut a synonym for `|` in the implementation of the play typeclass syntax. You can check the code above to see what it does :-) By the way: `(optA or optB or optB)(_.isDefined)` would solve the original posters question about finding if any of the options is defined.

Answer (score 0):

On an aesthetic basis:

```
scala> val a,b = Some(7)
a: Some[Int] = Some(7)
b: Some[Int] = Some(7)

scala> val c,d: Option[Int] = None
c: Option[Int] = None
d: Option[Int] = None

scala> a orElse b isDefined
res0: Boolean = true

scala> c orElse d isDefined
res1: Boolean = false

scala> a orElse c isDefined
res2: Boolean = true
```

I could do that all day.

```
scala> c orElse d orElse a orElse b isDefined
res3: Boolean = true
```

Yup, just checking that I could do it all day.